# Mask image in Xamarin Forms Android and iOS

Tags: image, xamarin, mask, alpha

I want to mask an image like the sample below:

[image: Image1]

I tried using the FFImageLoading Transformation, but I couldn't get the triangle shape that is in the image shown.

Also, I cannot do the trick of putting the background white, because I want to achieve this final result:

[image: Image2]

Is there any way to get the pixels of the triangle shape that are not in alpha, and convert them to the squared image pixels?

I tried this code from SkiaSharp changing the values of the SKPath, but this complicates more my problem because it is not an image, is a canvas:

```html
public class MonkeyThroughKeyholePage : ContentPage
    {
        SKBitmap bitmap;
        SKPath keyholePath = SKPath.ParseSvgPathData(
            "M 200 130 L 250 300 L 250 300 L 300 130 A 70 70 20 1 20 300 130 Z");

        public MonkeyThroughKeyholePage()
        {
            Title = "Monkey through Keyhole";

            SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
            canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
            Content = canvasView;

            string resourceID = "SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Media.SeatedMonkey.jpg";
            Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
            using (SKManagedStream skStream = new SKManagedStream(stream))
            {
                bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(skStream);
            }
        }

        void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {
            SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
            SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

            canvas.Clear();

            // Set transform to center and enlarge clip path to window height
            SKRect bounds;
            keyholePath.GetTightBounds(out bounds);

            canvas.Translate(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2);
            canvas.Scale(0.98f * info.Height / bounds.Height);
            canvas.Translate(-bounds.MidX, -bounds.MidY);

        //    canvas.RotateDegrees(15f);

            // Set the clip path
            canvas.ClipPath(keyholePath);

            // Reset transforms
            canvas.ResetMatrix();

            canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 
                new SKRect((info.Width - info.Height) / 2, 0,
                           (info.Width + info.Height) / 2, info.Height));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add sample code that shows your approach to the problem?

Comment: I already added a sample of code of what I'm tring to get so far

Comment: What did you eventually do here? Facing a similar challenge...